# Upload pdf file using cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

since i am new to cypress i have a scenario for uploading a pdf file where the HTML code is of not type 'file' it's 'text'

HTML code :

i have tried with following code :

```
 cy.get("input[placeholder='No Files selected']").invoke('attr', 'type', 'file')
 const fileName = "sample.pdf"
 cy.fixture(fileName).then(fileContent => {
   cy.get('[type="file"]').eq(1).upload({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/pdf' });
 })
```

i am not getting any error but the pdf is not uploaded.

please find the attach image for front-end

[image]`enter code here`

Comment: Can you show us the HTML/JS that corresponds to the button? There may be some custom JavaScript being used for the upload

Comment: HTML code for button is :      <img src="/attach-file-24-px.63367ef2.svg" alt="upload file" class="jss264">